# In C programming macros never do type check? Then what is the difference in defining macro for 0x01 and 0x01u?

Tags: c, macros

They say macros in c never checks for the data type, it simply replaces the left side with the right side. Then why people explicitly define the 0x01u as such they can simply say as 0x01?

Comment: At the place where the macro is used the check will be made

Comment: The macro (preprocessor) doesn't type check; the compiler does when the result of expanding the macro is used.

Comment: "...macros never do type check" - this can mean more than one thing. Clarify, what specifically you are asking about.

Comment: Thanks, Bernd Elkemann & Jonathan Leffler. I got your point  so in code where my macro gets replaced by the 0x01u it will be treated as unsigned int whereas for 0x01 it is simply treated as the signed int.

Comment: This question is not too bad. Bernds & Jonathans comments would make a fine answer.

Answer (score 0):

At the place where the macro is used the check will be made – Bernd Elkemann

The macro (preprocessor) doesn't type check; the compiler does when the result of expanding the macro is used. – Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score -1):

It defines an `unsigned` integer literal. You can also see where they defined a hex literal to be an `unsigned long` integer by using `0x…UL`.

If you would like to know the bit pattern they produce, simply translate the decimal literals to their equivalent hex or binary literals. `1U` becomes `0x01U` and `01b`<sup>1</sup> in hex and binary respectively.

Another more commonly seen literal uses the f-suffix, that is a single precision floating point literal like `1.0f`.

<sup>1. For illustration only; not an actual valid binary literal per the C standard. C++14 supports `0b01` for binary literals (and fun like `0b0000'0001` too, with `'` as a grouping character).</sup>

Comment: Please read the Question again, your answer doesn't seem to help the OP

Comment: @Rakesh_K I though he was asking what is the purpose of U symbol. So I delete my post. Thanks to notify me.